# ARCore Tracking Marker

Tags: android, arcore

I am developing an Android app that will simply track a real life marker and draw some graphics on top of that. I have just started looking into  frameworks... Is ARCore suitable for this or Vuforia ?

Comment: Vuforia will support ARCore after commercial release according to the forums. https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/vuforia-fusion-arcore#comment-62365

Comment: that means I will need to go with vuforia for tracking ?

Comment: I am not sure about that. But you should be able to do it without Vuforia too.

Comment: check this link -> https://www.andreasjakl.com/getting-started-with-google-arcore-part-2-visualizing-planes-placing-objects/

Comment: If you need to track an image target, then yes you need to use Vuforia

Comment: @Deepakkaku that link does mention tracking markers

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Currently ARCore 1.2 can use Images as tracking markers and then have AR objects attached to those points. However, ARCore image tracking does not track moving objects.

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unreal/augmented-images/